# csv data manipulation to keep and compare large of each class

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to alter a piece of code in order to perform the following.

In each dataclass (`column1`) convert the weight into pounds. Calculate for each dataclass what the largest weight is. And for each line of the dataclass work out the difference between the weight assigned to the person in that row and the largest in their class (`dataclass`) and append to a new column.

It is probably a relatively simple manipulation, but I didnt know how to keep each large of the weights in memory for each data class. My code can turn the weight into pounds but this is much simpler because I can just loop straight through the csv row by row, not needing to rememeber previous data for the data class.

An example csv dataset:

```
data,dataclass1,8-10,data,data
data,dataclass1,9-06,data,data
data,dataclass1,10-00,data,data
data,dataclass1,14-10,data,data
data,dataclass1,12-10,data,data
data,dataclass1,8-11,data,data
data,dataclass1,16-10,data,data
data,dataclass1,20-10,data,data
data,dataclass1,18-10,data,data
data,dataclass2,20-10,data,data
data,dataclass2,8-10,data,data
data,dataclass2,9-06,data,data
data,dataclass2,10-00,data,data
data,dataclass2,14-10,data,data
data,dataclass2,12-10,data,data
data,dataclass2,18-10,data,data
data,dataclass2,8-11,data,data
data,dataclass2,10-00,data,data
data,dataclass2,14-10,data,data
data,dataclass2,12-10,data,data
data,dataclass3,12-10,data,data
data,dataclass3,18-10,data,data
data,dataclass3,8-11,data,data
data,dataclass3,10-00,data,data
data,dataclass3,14-10,data,data
data,dataclass3,12-10,data,data
data,dataclass3,18-10,data,data
data,dataclass3,8-11,data,data
data,dataclass3,10-00,data,data
data,dataclass3,14-10,data,data
```

The code I have to turn hyphenated weights into pounds:

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv') as f:
    with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as w:
        c = [r for r in csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')]
        data = [
            item[0] * 14 + item[1] for item in
                [map(int, row[2].split('-', 1)) for row in c]
        ]
        for line, d in zip(c, data):
            for l in line:
                w.writelines(str(l) + ',')
            w.writelines(str(d))
            w.writelines('\n')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a dictionary for this easily.

```
weightDict = dict()
for line in open("filename").readlines():
    items=line.split(",")
    c = items[1]
    if c not in weightDict.keys():
        weightDict[c] = []
    weightDict[c].append(convertToPounds(items[2])) #call your conversion function here

for c in weightDict.keys(): #loop over all classes seen
    print("class: " + c + "max: " + str(max(weightDict[c])) #calls max function on all weights for this class
```

This function prints the classes and their maximum weights, but you can write them or do whatever you like instead by modifying the last loop.